# How do I make a column very wide in Handsontable?

Tags: jquery, css, handsontable

When using Handsontable (http://handsontable.com), I can't seem to make a column wider than a certain amount.   For example, I'd like to make a column 600 pixels wide.

But when I set colWidth property:

```
$("#example1").handsontable({
    data: myData,
    colWidths: [600, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47], //can also be a number or a       function
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    fixedRowsTop: 2,
    fixedColumnsLeft: 2,
    contextMenu: true
  });
```

It doesn't get bigger than about 200 pixels.

The container div dimensions don't seem to matter either.

Here's a modified example from the handsontable site, where I set the colWidth to 800 and the container to 1400px:
http://jsfiddle.net/RSJQ3/

Comment: https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/797. Its a known bug, you can go into the actual js file and set it to greater than 200px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already known.
Have a look [here](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/706) for issue 706
@stackErr is referring to another issue which is to do with row header width and not the column header width which this question is asking about.

However, he is right that you can change the handsontable js file and set it to greater than 200.

The row header width can be changed in the css file:

```
.handsontable col.rowHeader
```